# Why does Auth0 fails with error unknown client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authorization, auth0

I have a React project using express/node.js on the backend.  Tested the project thoroughly before deploying, fully functional with no problems.  After hosting and configuration, the site is accessible online but any login attempt generates a 400 error stating the request is coming from an unknown client?

I can share any code snippets needed but I'm thinking something is wrong in my Auth0 configuration.  I've checked and triple-checked the clientID and key in my code, as well as my web origin urls and allowed callback URLs.

Can't find any reference to this error code here on stack or on google.  Auth0 support has no mention.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Juti Hello, I'm having a similar issue when calling the interface. Is your problem solved? How was it solved? Can you share it?